# How find next element of an anchor using with htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Here is my html elements :

```
<a href="#" class="A">Sana</a>
<b><span class="B">1000</span>Dollar</b>
```

I Want to read 1000(price) using with htmlagilitypack.
`Sana` innerText in unique, but Dollar innerText is not unique.
Also there are many classes in goal page with name `A` & `B`.
I want to read an anchor(`element a`) that has `Sana` innerText & find next element of that anchor(`element b`) & read innerText of that.
Here is my codes :

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("goal web site");
req.Method = "GET";
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*;q=0.8";
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
req.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
req.Referer = "";
req.KeepAlive = true;
req.Timeout = 25000;
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

CookieContainer cookieJar1 = new CookieContainer();
req.CookieContainer = cookieJar1;

HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();

foreach(Cookie cookie in res.Cookies) {
    cookieJar1.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name.Trim(), cookie.Value.Trim(), "/", cookie.Domain));
}

Stream Stream = res.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Stream);
string reader_str = reader.ReadToEnd();

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(reader_str);
```

Here what should i do to read 1000 price?

```
reader.Close();
Stream.Close();
res.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following XPath<sup>*</sup> expression:

```
var xpath = "//a[.='Sana']/following-sibling::b[1]/span";
string price = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                      .SelectSingleNode(xpath)
                      .InnerText;
Console.WriteLine(price.Text);
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4xq5K6)</kbd>**

XPath expression break down:

- **`//a[.='Sana']`**: find `<a>` elements that has inner text equals 'Sana' anywhere in the document
- **`/following-sibling::b[1]`**: find the first sibling element `<b>` that located after `<a>` elements found in the previous step
- **`/span`**: find `<span>` element that is child of `<b>` elements found in the previous step

*) Read up on "XPath" topic if you are not familiar with it. This is one from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx